# Azure worker role:Reading certificate from cert store using c# removes private key

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I am trying to read certificate from cert store in the worker role using C#.
But i ended up with the error 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: keyset does not exist'.And looks like the .net code removes the private key while forming the certstorecollection.

Below is the C# code i used,
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

```
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "MyThumbPrint", false);

        if (certCollection.Count != 0)
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
            WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            this.HttpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        }
```

Could you please let me know if i miss any code in retaining the key.

Your help at the earliest is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you adding the certificates? Can you check if the certificates are installed with private keys? You can find that out by connecting to your worker role instance via RDP.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I connected to worker role via RDP and checked in the cert manager. I could not find my certificate in the remote desktop.Can you please tell me how can i find my certificate in here.

Comment: That's weird. If the certificate is not present, then you should get the error in the code also. Are you checking the correct certificate store. From your code, it seems you are installing the certificate in `LocalMachine` store.

Comment: I wanted to read the certificate that I have added inside the worker role in the azure portal.can you please help me in accomplishing this.What is the best way of reading the certificate and use it in htto call.